# SELECT and COUNT from relative table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, forums and topics. Each topic belongs to a forum, which is specified by a forum_id. To each forum I want to return the belonging topics count in the same query.

```
SELECT  (
SELECT *
FROM  forums
) AS forums,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  topics t
WHERE t.forum_id=forums.id
) AS topic_count
```

How can I pass the ID from first select and compare it in the second?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (hence just a comment), but from a database design the standard for table names is singular. `forums` would be `forum`, `topics` would be `topic` and a table for users would be `user`. I know we often don't have control over naming, but just a suggestion if this is a new database. Also, I think Gordon's answer is correct, although it might have a minor syntax error or two (I haven't tried to run it).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT f.*, COUNT(*)
FROM forums f
     topics t
     on t.forum_id = forums.id
GROUP BY f.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *, (Select Count(*) From topics t2 
    Where t2.forum_id=t1.Forums_id) As [Topic Count] 
    From forums t1
    Order By t1.forums_id
```